# Confusion of creation_time field of mysql table in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, datetime, timestamp

Any idea why I cannot automatically update creation_time field in my table:

id | name | creation_time

**creation_time**-->
Type: Timestamp,
Default Value: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

When I try to save data in cakephp by using a statement like this:

```
$this->Model->create();
$this->Model->save(array('name'=>'...'));
```

I got new data inserting to the table but without the creation time.  It is abnormal that when i run an **insert into** Mysql statement then the field is automatically update as current timestamp.

I know that I could use created field as in Cakephp's documentation but for my case, i don't want to change the existing field name because it is a table used by other members working in the same project.

Please advise me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `$this->Model->create()`, Cake populates the data contained in `$this->Model` with default values. If you debug `$this->Model->data`

```
debug($this->Model->data);
```

You will that the `creation_time` is already set, but with a string:

```
array(
    'Model' => array(
         ...,
         'creation_time' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
)
```

)

So when Cake generates the INSERT query, this one contain the `creation_time` field, with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a string:

```
INSERT INTO `models` (..., `creation_time`, ...) VALUES (..., 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', ...)
```

If you want to keep your `creation_time` field in the datatable, to generate a working query you could delete the default value before saving the data:

```
$this->Model->create();
unset($this->Model->data['Model']['creation_time']);
$this->Model->save(...);
```

Comment: Thanks. I wrote an override function save() in model file and it works really well.

Answer (score 2):

In cakephp it is better to use the conventional names like "created" in your case.
The field will be datetime type. But if you wanna make your own field you have to insert manually into your field the actually date and time with a normal set example:

```
$this->Model->set('creation_time', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

where current_timestamp is your variable that you have to create and after you save your model

But the best way in cakephp is to use the convention names, isn't recommended to use unconvention names